# Mod rewrite question. Help!

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to set up a basic rewrite and it is not working. I want to be able to achieve the following:

```
http://www.example.com/view.php?page=1
```

Rewrite to

```
http://www.example.com/view/1
```

I have tried everything I can find and nothing seems to be working.

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE:
These seems to be working but I requires the page to be redirected and I would prefer not to have to do that. The output is not exactly what I wanted as the querystring is still visible.

```
output: http://www.example.com/view/1?page=1

Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /view.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([A-Za-z0-9\+]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /view/%1 [R=301,QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ /view.php?page=$1&a=1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#rewriting rule to set last /
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)$  /view/$1/ [QSA,R] 

#rewriting rule to pass $1 as page that is the first element inside (...)
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/$ view.php?page=$1
```

Edit: Also make sure that your mod_rewrite module on apache is enabled ;)

Comment: "RewriteRule ^(view)/(1)$  /$1/$1/ [QSA,R]" is "RewriteRule ^(view)/(1)$  /$1/$2/ [QSA,R] "

Comment: Is the module enabled?? You should try to write a basic rewrite rule to check it! Let me know, I will try it on my webserver if it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/view/([0-9]+)/?$ /view.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Did you get rid of your other lines?  Also make sure you have rewrite enabled properly in htaccess and in your Apache config.

Comment: Yes, I removed everything and just had this rule.

Comment: You haven't provided a lot of info on what happens when it is not working.  Does the url "/view.php?page=23" for example, exist and you are able to visit it?  Please provide the URL as you enter it (which should match the first part of the rewrite) and the rule as exists when visited normally.  Seeing these two URLs may help solve your problem.